# Correct way to subscribe and unsubscribe React Native Netinfo

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-community-netinfo

Based on the documentation in here to subscribe and unsubscribe Netinfo listener - https://github.com/react-native-netinfo/react-native-netinfo

I define the listener method in a common file and export it

```
/* util.js */
function listener(){
  Netinfo.addEventListener(state => /* something in here */);
}

export { listener };
```

Then in a React component

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { listener } from 'util';

const exampleComponent = props => {
  
  // then on useeffect
  useEffect(() => {
    listener() // to subscribe

    return () => listener(); // to unsubscribe
  }, []);

  return <ExampleComponent />
}
```

Is this the correct way to setup Netinfo listener if i want to make listener as an exportable method that can be setup anywhere (altho by logic it should only be set up on the main file in the app, but just for the sake of question)?

Im not sure how calling `listener` the first time will subscribe Netinfo listener and calling it again will unsubscribe it.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this the correct way to setup Netinfo listener if i want to make listener as an exportable method that can be setup anywhere (altho by logic it should only be set up on the main file in the app, but just for the sake of question)?

if you want to setup once and use it many times, no need to do that by yourself, you can use [useNetInfo()](https://github.com/react-native-netinfo/react-native-netinfo#usenetinfo)

```js
import {useNetInfo} from "@react-native-community/netinfo";

const YourComponent = () => {

  const netInfo = useNetInfo();

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Type: {netInfo.type}</Text>
      <Text>Is Connected? {netInfo.isConnected.toString()}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,

```
    import NetInfo from "@react-native-community/netinfo";
    
    const [isConnected, setIsConnected] = useState(true);
    
    NetInfo.fetch().then(state => {
            if (state.isConnected && state.isInternetReachable) {
                setIsConnected(true);
            } else {
                setIsConnected(false);
            }
        });
    
    useEffect(() => {
            const unsubscribe = NetInfo.addEventListener(state => {
                if (state.isConnected && state.isInternetReachable) {
                    setIsConnected(true);
                } else {
                    setIsConnected(false);
                }
            });
            if (isConnected) {
                
            } else {
                unsubscribe();
            }
        }, []);
```